# Android how to do validation for Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

i have 4 spinners all have same options but i want to restrict user,when he select one option in one spinner ,then he is not going to select same option another by poping an alert dialog. Can any buddy give sample code for it and one more thing i want to add one default optoin in Spinner say "Select One" but im buinding data to Spinner at Runtime ,so im able to add that Select one option in all the Spinners.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(otherSpinner.getSelectedItem().equals(someItem)
                      if(/* this one should not be selected*/) { 
                               ;/* alert */
                               ;/* reset selection on this spinner */
                       }
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                showToast(q.name + " unselected");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I want to use a Spinner that initially (when the user has not made a selection yet) displays the text "Select One". When the user clicks the spinner, the list of items is displayed and the user selects one of the options. After the user has made a selection, the selected item is displayed in the Spinner instead of "Select One". and also im bind data with spinner at runtime .

Comment: spinners don't have any prompt in newer versions of android software

Comment: can i add it like this Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayList<String> yourIngredients = new ArrayList<String>();
//GET ALL INGREDIENTS
//yourIngredients.add(INGREDIENT)
//FINALLY
yourIngredients.add("NONE");
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourIngredients.toArray());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: something like that will work to get a prompt when you start. but after the user has selected something, its' hard to remove the prompt from the list.